# Draw a border around all objects/shapes in a QGraphicsItem paint method

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside2, qgraphicsitem, qpainter

I want to draw a border around all objects/shapes within a `QGraphicsItem` Paint method. (*The green and red circles are part of a separate item, so they don't count in this situation*)

I am currently drawing `RoundedRects`, but I'm looking for a scalable solution that could also support more complicated objects (stars, bananas, etc); situations where you have objects overlaid on each other.

I have an Item that, when selected, changes the border colour of two `RoundedRects`.
[image]

[image]

I want a solution where only the outline border changes colour, not the internal.

Possible methods I think might work are using a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` or creating a `QtCore.Qt.MaskOutColor` and controlling the line thickness, somehow. I've done this before by scaling up a duplicate masked shape, but the results aren't ideal. So I'd be really interested in hearing other people's solutions!

This is my basic `QGraphicsItem`.

```
class Node(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__(parent)

        scene.addItem(self)

        # Variables
        self.main_background_colour = QtGui.QColor(31, 176, 224)
        self.title_background_colour = QtGui.QColor("#fffeb3")
        self.name_background_colour = QtGui.QColor("#b8b64b")
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush(self.main_background_colour)
        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(self.title_text_colour, 2)

        self.main_rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 400, 200)
        self.title_rect = QtCore.QRectF(self.main_rect.x() + (self.main_rect.width() * 0.05), self.main_rect.y() - 10, (self.main_rect.width() * 0.9), (self.main_rect.height() * 0.2))
        self.name_rect = QtCore.QRectF(self.main_rect.x() + (self.main_rect.width() * 0.02), self.title_rect.bottom() - 10, (self.main_rect.width() * 0.96), (self.main_rect.height() * 0.3))
        self.name_font_rect = QtCore.QRectF(self.name_rect.x() + (self.name_rect.width() * 0.05), self.name_rect.y() + 10, self.name_rect.width() * 0.9, self.name_rect.height() * 0.65)

        # Flags
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsFocusable, True)

        self.setCacheMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.DeviceCoordinateCache)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.main_rect.x(), self.title_rect.y(), self.main_rect.width(), self.main_rect.height() + abs(self.main_rect.y() + self.title_rect.y()))

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):

        # Border
        if self.isSelected():
            border_colour = QtGui.QColor(241, 175, 0)

        else:
            border_colour = self.main_background_colour.lighter()

        self.pen.setColor(border_colour)
        self.pen.setWidth(2)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)

        # Background
        self.brush.setColor(self.main_background_colour)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.main_rect, 4, 4)

        # Name
        self.brush.setColor(self.name_background_colour)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        self.pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor("black"))
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.name_rect, 4, 4)


        # Tile
        self.brush.setColor(self.title_background_colour)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        self.pen.setColor(border_colour)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)

        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.title_rect, 4, 4)
```

**UPDATE**
I have tried using the paint method as shown in [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71776090/3950707) answer, but it draws a border around all Rects individually, rather than the overall exterior shape.

The rest of my base code is the same, but I have changed the paint to match [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71776090/3950707) reply.
[image]

```
def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):

    path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    path.setFillRule(QtCore.Qt.WindingFill)

    for rect in (self.main_rect, self.name_rect, self.title_rect):
        path.addRoundedRect(rect, 4, 4)

    if self.isSelected():
        border_colour = QtGui.QColor(241, 175, 0)
    else:
        border_colour = self.main_background_colour.lighter()

    painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(border_colour, 2))
    painter.drawPath(path)
```

To clarify, this is the border I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (but yet not optimal) solution is to create a [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) based on all the rectangles, and draw the "final" border joining all the shapes the item contains:

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        # draw all items here, using default values
        # ...

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)

        for rect in (self.main_rect, self.name_rect, self.title_rect):
            path.addRoundedRect(rect, 4, 4)

        if self.isSelected():
            border_colour = QtGui.QColor(241, 175, 0)
        else:
            border_colour = self.main_background_colour.lighter()

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(border_colour, 2))
        painter.drawPath(path.simplified())
```

Be aware, though, that painting functions are called **very** often. Some level of caching and existing implementation is always preferred, especially considering that python is a **huge** bottleneck: you should always try to take advantage of the C++ implementation, possibly with existing base QGraphicsItem shapes.

For instance, instead of always painting three rounded rects from python, you could use a QGraphicsPathItem with a predefined QGraphicsPath set for each item.

Since you're already setting the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag, you could override `itemChange()` to update that path whenever required, so that you don't need to create a new QPainterPath object for every `paint()` call.

And if those items are used to show text, then use a QGraphicsPathItem with a [QGraphicsSimpleTextItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssimpletextitem.html) set as a child of it.

Alternatively, consider using a [QPicture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpicture.html) as a class/instance variable that would be used as a "middle-cache" object: while it might add some level of complexity in the implementation, it certainly would improve performance, especially when multiple items are being shown.

Comment: I'm interested in optimising as much as possible; would creating an additional QGraphicsPathItem be better than drawing these shapes in the paint method? The QGraphicsPathItem paint method will be firing just as much as the parent QGraphicsItem paint method, right? Or are you saying separating these Objects has better C++ implementation, so is more optimal overall?  Thanks for your message, this is really interesting.

Comment: @AdamSirrelle the point is: the less you use python overrides, the faster the execution is, since it only uses the C++ implementation (and C++/python/C++ "passage"). If you just add those items as "static" objects, instead of creating them every time you paint the object, and let Qt do *all* the painting, it will be inevitably faster. Remember that painting can happen ***very*** often, especially if items are interactive or support hover actions (or intersect items that do). Try to add a print statement there and you'll see.

Comment: Is that the same for basic geometry like DrawRect, and DrawRounded rect, or is this something which is more beneficial for complex shapes. BTW, I was unable to draw the border around the final shape, as detailed above, it drew borders around all the roundedRects that were added to the QPainterPath.

Comment: @AdamSirrelle the matter is not about what you call, but what you actually do. Just overriding a method adds some level of overhead (the binding calls the python method, then it "replies" to the C++ side). Even overriding `paint()` and just calling the base implementation creates a bottleneck: it's usually small, but if you have tens, hundreds or even thousands of items, and that function is usually called very often, the overhead is increased exponentially. About the last comment, did you actually use the `WindingFill` rule? Because from what you're describing, it seems like you didn't.

Comment: @AdamSirrelle and, it should go without saying, if you add child QGraphicsItems, you should **not** override `paint()` and do the painting on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it's really helpful! I'm currently implementing these optimisations :D  I used WindingFill. I even tried hashing out everything in Paint, and replacing it with your code above, but it just draws borders on the three separate rects.

Comment: @AdamSirrelle Then pleawse [edit] your question and update the details so that we could try to help you. But please remember that we still need a proper [mre], which will speed up our understanding of the problem as much as other people looking for similar issues.

Comment: OK, I managed to get this working by simplifying the path after setting the border_colour.    path = path.simplified()    This combines the rects before they are drawn, providing me with the desired affect. If you are happy with this solution, could you update your code and I'll mark it as the answer as you got me 99% of the way there, and provided a lot of useful insight. : )

Comment: @AdamSirrelle sorry, I forgot that the path has to be `simplified()` to avoid the multiple rectangles.